# jQuery Closest - how does it work?

Tags: jquery

The jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) states

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

The operational word here, to my eyes, is **ancestor**.  Which would imply that if one uses

```
elem.closest(selector)
```

and selector is not an ancestor of elem nothing will be found. However, a little lower down in the same document it reads

> Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector

which I interpret as meaning that it will go all the way up to the <body> tag to get its man. Note, no mention of *parent* or *ancestor* here.

I wrote up a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCGGV/) which appears to suggest that it is the former statement that is correct.  However, I thought it best to post here and see if anyone else can confirm this.

Comment: The two statements aren't mutually exclusive, in fact they mean the same thing. It will indeed go up to the <body> tag, it will go do the document root.

Comment: You are right, I think.  Neither statement is wrong.  But that still leaves me feeling slightly confused. In my fiddle the first input has a div with a data-x attribute as its immediate ancestor and closest reports finding it.  The second input does not have such a div as an ancestor but it does exist as its parent div's sibling but it does not get found

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The implementation of `.closest()` works like this (in pseudo code):

```
while (node) {
  if (node matches selector) {
    return node;
  }
  node := node.parentNode
}
```

In other words, it traverses up by following the parent chain only.

Comment: Your pseudocode confirms the behavior I see.  `node := node.previous` is how I interpreted the docs.

Comment: @DroidOS That would be the behaviour of `.prevAll(selector).first()` :)

Answer (score 5):

When it says "Travels up the DOM tree" in the second quote, it means "traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree" in your first quote. There's no difference between both of the statements quoted; one is a paraphrase of the other that just happens to be slightly less specific.

Comment: But why in that case does clicking on the second input in my fiddle - the one which does not have a div bearing the data-x attrib as an immediate parent - does closest find nothing? If it goes all the way the DOM tree it should have found the parent div of the first input which DOES have data-x attribute.

Comment: @DroidOS: Yes, it finds nothing. Why should it have found the parent of the first input when it's *not* the parent of the second input?

Comment: This is what I find confusing.  Now you are talking _parent_.  A minute ago we were talking about going up the DOM tree.  Going up the DOM tree I understood to mean it just gets its man no matter whether it is a parent or not. Note that the docs do not mention parent at all.

Comment: @DroidOS: A parent is an immediate ancestor. An ancestor is some element that contains your element, which means any of your parents' parents/ancestors are also your own ancestors. As you've found, the behavior matches what is described in your first quote. The second statement is nothing more than a paraphrase of the first.

Comment: You are right, I guess.  The behavior is what I require - I just wanted to check here before I hang myself on it.  I was concerned that &lt;body&gt; being the ultimate ancestor would throw a spanner in the works - particularly in view of the fact that the second statement does not mention the words ancestor or parent.

Comment: @DroidOS: While "going *down* the DOM tree" does imply searching through every element within some other element, that's because an element can have any number of children, and all children that share the same parent are siblings of one another. However, an individual child element can only have one parent (this applies to *every* element except the root element), so "going *up* the DOM tree" means searching only parents/ancestors.

Answer (score 2):

.closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Ex:

```
$( "li.item-a" ).closest( "ul" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

This will change the color of the level-2 , since it is the first encountered when traveling up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery closest() selects first parent element (by it HTML tag) of the selector, or selector itself (if it matches). It's like if you are selecting 'p' element ($('p#someid')), it starts searching from your 'p' element and if there is no match, it moves to it's parent. And so on

Example HTML:

```
<div id='select_me'>Div
    <p id='id'>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

`$('#id').closest('div)` // will select `div#select_me`, as closest parent div

where as

```
 <p id='select_me'>Div
    <p id='select_me_now'>paragraph</p>
</p>
```

`$('#select_me_now').closest("p");` // will select `p#select_me_now` itself