# Find a Form without Id and add input element to that

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to add an input element to a form whose id i don't know. code below worked great if there is only one form in the page

```
var dd = document.createElement("div");
dd.id = "cont";
dd.name = "cont";
var pp = document.createElement("input");
pp.type = "password";
pp.name = "pass";
dd.appendChild(pp);

document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].appendChild(dd);
```

but when there are more than 1 form in the page then this input element get appended to the first form with the above code.
Remember I don't know how many forms are there in the html page. and user can place the script in any form in the page. so how do i make sure that the input element get appended to the right form. some one suggested jquery closest() function but I prefer pure javascript.
  One working example is google recaptcha. there recaptcha challenge textbox appear exactly where u put the script and exactly in the form u want.

so guys any help in pure javascript code will be much appreciated.

thanx..

Comment: How can we know what form is right?

Comment: Show HTML, and how would you know to what form to append element (from human perspective).

Comment: Why not use `'name'` attribute for the form tag?

Comment: How is your code called? Is it a `<script>` tag that gets inserted into a document?

Comment: If you are looking for `closest` in pure JS, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463186/jquery-closest-how-does-it-work#19463246. It should help you.

Comment: No way to know which form is right

Comment: guys the input element going to be added with javascript using <script></script> tage inside the form where i want the text box to appear in the form. It could be any form in the page having any name or id. user can just put the <script src="anydomain.com/script.js"></script> tag in there form where they want this textbox appear. the code below suggested by "user3678068" work fine in firefox and chrome but failed in IE and I haven't tested in other browswe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert `input` tag into the same form in which you placed the script tag. You can reference the particular form like this

```
var form = document.currentScript.parentNode;
form.appendChild(dd);
```

Comment: This is not as widely supported amongst browsers.

Comment: this code works gr8 on firefox and Chrome but failed in IE.. Anyways I m gonna stick with this..

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Class` to the `form`, 
and in the javascript fet the form by class name

`document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].appendChild(dd);`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()`. And it is more or less the same as accessing elements by tag name. Reread the question. The first sentence after the code.

Comment: sorry I missed it Thanks nicael.